# Avoid duplicate matching if the match precedes with whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string containing names such as

```
"james frederick ricky rick jones"
```

I want to split this string by the FIRST matching "rick" that precedes by a whitespace

The code is as follows (in C#)

```
string source = "james frederick ricky rick jones";
string expression = "(rick)(?<!\1.*\1)";

string[] chunks = Regex.Split(source, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The result I'm get is something like this

```
[0] - "james frede"
[1] - "rick"
[2] - "ricky rick jones"
```

Is it possible to change or modify the regular expression to get the following result?

```
[0] - "james frederick"
[1] - "rick"
[2] - "y rick jones"
```

Comment: What do you mean by first **FIRST matching "rick"**, what if there are **many ricky rick afterwards**? If FIRST means **only one**, the `string.IndexOf` is much simpler.

Comment: in my example it matches the "rick" in Frederick. but I only need to match only the first "rick" precedes with a whitespace. if there are many ricky or rick afterwards, they shouldn't match.

Comment: Then why do you choose `regex` instead of `IndexOf`, considering performance, maintainability, and also simplicity(that is why you are asking here)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:\s)+(rick)
```

`(?:\s)+` is a non selecting capture group checks for 1 or more matches of space before "rick" so should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This one breaks the string into three capture groups:

```
(.+?) (rick)(.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/UceAEC/2

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to your attempt. Put a space before the "rick" in the regex.

```
string source = "james frederick ricky rick jones";
string expression = @"(\srick)(?<!\1.*\1)";

string[] chunks = Regex.Split(source, expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var ch = chunks.Select(c =>c.TrimStart());
```

Note: this literally will find rick preceded by a whitespace as you asked for in the question.